# Pivot some rows and Unpivot columns together Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I want Pivot as well as Unpivot at the same time.

Below is the sample example.
I have Oracle 11G R1. SQL /PLSQL anything can be used.
Appreciate your time.

```
ID Subid Col1 Col2
------------------
1    23   AB   4T4
1    16   AV   654
--The id can have multiple subid,its not fixed, so it has to be dynamic.That dynamic IN clause I can generate
```

Desired OUTPUT:

```
ID Col_name Subid_23 SubId_16
-----------------------------
1   Col1       AB       FD  
1   Col2       4T4      654
```

Comment: Will every `id` in the source have two rows one with `subid` 23 and one with `subid` 16?  Or are you implying that you want the number of results (and the names of the columns) in the result to be dynamic?

Comment: @JustinCave No, the id column can have multiple rows. Yes it has to be dynamic, I am planning to use dynamic sql to generate the IN clause

Comment: OK, so you know that you need to use dynamic SQL.  I assume that means that you've seen some of the questions here on SO and elsewhere that talk about how to construct a dynamic pivot.  What have you tried and what step in the process are you stuck on?